# Find all files with given extension in subfolders, and add substring corresponding to subfolder

Tags: command-line, bash, python3, find, batch-rename

I have numerous `txt` files, scattered across different folders.

```
- case1
   |
    - 0.25
       |
        - case1.txt
    - 0.35
       |
        _ case1.txt
    - 0.30
       |
        _ case1.txt
    - 0.45
       |
        _ case1.txt

- case2
   |
    - 0.25
       |
        - case2.txt
    - 0.35
       |
        _ case2.txt
    - 0.30
       |
        _ case2.txt
    - 0.45
       |
        _ case2.txt

.
.
.
```

I would like to copy them all to a folder, but unfortunately, as you can see, some of them have the same name, and thus a naive `find` solution ends up overwriting them. I would like to copy all the `txt` files to a directory `foo`, inserting the name of the name of the subfolder they're in, before the `.txt` extension. Also, since that the subfolder has a dot in the name, and I need to copy these files to Windows, I'd also like to change `0.25` to `0_25`. In other words, the file

```
- case2
   |
    - 0.25
       |
        - case2.txt
```

must be copied to `foo` as `case2_0_25.txt`. If a bash solution is too complex/unreadable, a Python solution would be fine too, but **not** a zsh one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily enough using the globstar option of bash (from `man bash`):

> globstar
>
> If set, the pattern `**` used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and subdirectories match.

Since we can use `**` to find the files, we just need to define the new name as including the original directory names and changing `.` to `_`:

```
for file in **/*.txt; do 
    newName=$(sed 's|[/.]|_|g' <<<"$file" | sed 's/_txt$/.txt/')
    cp -- "$file" foo/"$newName" 
done
```

#### Explanation

- `for file in **/*.txt; do`: find all files (and directories, if that's relevant) in the current directory whose name ends in `*.txt`.
- `newName=$(sed 's|[/.]|_|g' <<<"$file" | sed 's/_txt$/.txt/')` :  use `sed` to convert all `/` and `.` to `_` in the file name. Note that `$file` here also includes the path, so it will be something like `case1/0.25/case1.txt` and that becomes `case1_0_25_case1_txt`. We then pass the output of the first `sed` to a second one which converts `_txt` (if found at the end of the line) to `.txt`, giving us ``case1_0_25_case1.txt`. The final output is saved in the variable` $newName`.
- `cp -- "$file" foo/"$newName"`: we now copy the file to the directory `foo/` and with the new name. The `--` is not really needed here, but ensures the approach will work with any file name, including those whose name starts with a `-`.

I recreated the folder structure you show in your question, ran the command above and got:

```
$ tree
.
├── case1
│   ├── 0.25
│   │   └── case1.txt
│   ├── 0.30
│   │   └── case1.txt
│   ├── 0.35
│   │   └── case1.txt
│   └── 0.45
│       └── case1.txt
├── case2
│   ├── 0.25
│   │   └── case2.txt
│   ├── 0.30
│   │   └── case2.txt
│   ├── 0.35
│   │   └── case2.txt
│   └── 0.45
│       └── case2.txt
└── foo
    ├── case1_0_25_case1.txt
    ├── case1_0_30_case1.txt
    ├── case1_0_35_case1.txt
    ├── case1_0_45_case1.txt
    ├── case2_0_25_case2.txt
    ├── case2_0_30_case2.txt
    ├── case2_0_35_case2.txt
    └── case2_0_45_case2.txt

11 directories, 16 files
```

Answer (score 3):

You divide the copy into two transformations where the first step translates dots and slashes to underscore, and the next rearranges the matched subexpressions into the desired order.

```
shopt -s globstar; \
tar -cvf - --show-transformed-names --transform='s![.]!_!g' --transform='s!.*/\([^/]\+\)/\([^/]\+\)_txt$!foo/\2_\1.txt!' case*/**/*.txt | tar -xf -
```

Now, it's crucial `--transform` matches, or those files will go through unprocessed.

A Bash solution will work much the same way.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob globstar

mkdir -p foo
while read -rd ''; do
    [[ ${REPLY//./_} =~ ([^/]+)/([^/]+)_txt$ ]] && 
        cp -va "$REPLY" "foo/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.txt"
done < <(printf %s\\0 case*/**/*.txt)
```